# Received 404 Error on Webservice using .Net Core

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.1

So really the first time attempting to create a REST webservice and dealing with any web stuff. Have been following this guide: http://www.patrickschadler.com/creating-a-rest-webservice-with-net-core/

It uses a very bare bones approach (like this approach as I do not require all the bloatware that is added when selecting the "**Web Application**" option).

However, as I have followed the example:

1. Ran the program as is (Saw the hello world response)
2. Then added the read write controller
3. Added items to Startup.cs

Then attempted to call : https://localhost:44325/api/r_w , this resulted in a 404 response that I can see in the project debug output window and within the browser as well.

I have had a look around and a lot of people use the **Web Application** selection adding a few other files and dependencies and the solutions to those issues do not help.

Initially I thought it was with the way the route is written out:

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        });
```

However, as some solutions that I have searched have suggested changing the route has not had any effect for me unfortunately.

I even attempted to use routedebugger, however under **Dependencies/Nuget** in solution explorer, it displays that there are issues with compatibility and will not work as expected.

Then found this to be very helpful: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Below is the startup file:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        //app.Run(async (context) =>
        //{
        //    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        //});
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        //app.UseMvc();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        });
    }
}
```

A small snippet from the read/write controller (entirely unchanged from when a person adds it to the project):

```
namespace deliver_data.wwwroot.Controllers
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class r_wController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET: api/r_w
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

Would really like to get this example to work, seems to be the simplest one out there. Just not really understanding why it won't work. Is there a major lack of understanding of something from my point of view?

Comment: Have you tried route without an action at all: template: "{controller=Home}/{id?}"?

Comment: FYI, the template you're applying using `MapRoute` does not apply to `r_wController`, simply because [attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1#attribute-routing) (using `Route` and `HttpGet`) essentially takes priority over [conventional routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1#conventional-routing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your namespace here looks *unusual* - It suggests you have a folder structure that looks something like this:

- wwwroot

  - Controllers

    - r_wController.cs
- deliver_data.csproj
- ...

Controller classes that live inside of `wwwroot` will not be picked up: This is a special folder in ASP.NET Core that represents raw resources that you want your application to serve.

In order to fix this, pull your `Controllers` folder up a level, outside of the `wwwroot` folder, like so:

- Controllers

  - r_wController.cs
- wwwroot

  - ...
- deliver_data.csproj
- ...

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
namespace deliver_data.wwwroot.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class r_wController : ControllerBase
    {
       // GET: api/r_w
       [HttpGet]
       public IHttpActionResult Get()
       {
           return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
       }
```

Comment: Why would that make a difference? And would it even compile?